# too many initializers for struct

Tags: c++, struct, avr, atmelstudio

I'm currently working on a EEprom file structure which is filled with default values while compiling. All works fine so far except for one structure and i can't seem to find the error..

```
typedef struct { // ===== instance parameters =====
        BOOL bInstanceActive; 
        BYTE nInstanceGrp[4];
        BYTE nEventFilter;
        BYTE nEventScheme;
        BYTE nEventPriority;
        BYTE nShortMul;
        BYTE nDoubleMul;
        BYTE nRepeatMul;
        BYTE nStuckMul;
        BYTE nDummy[3];
    } InstanceBlock;
#define DEFAULT_INSTANCE_BLOCK  {1, {255,255,255,255}, 244, 0, 2, 15, 5, 10, 30, {0}}
```

The Types "BOOL" and "BYTE" are both unsigned char.

the different structs are then combined to one EEprom_Mapping struct (but i currently only have this one in it, all others work fine):

```
typedef struct {
    InstanceBlock xInstance[1];    ** edited should be 1 instead of 0
    } EEprom_Mapping;
#define DEFAULT_EEprom_Mapping { DEFAULT_INSTANCE_BLOCK }
```

It is then initialized this way:

```
EEprom_Mapping xEE __attribute__((section(".eeprom"))) = DEFAULT_EEprom_Mapping;
```

The error message is "too many initializers for 'InstanceBlock [0]'"

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Which is it - C or C++?

Comment: Well, one is larger than zero. Anyway, C++ doesn't allow zero length automatic storage arrays.

Comment: Please tag the language correctly: this is why this otherwise good question is being downvoted.

Comment: So with your edit, and according your comment, if you change `xInstance[0]` to `xInstance[1]` their is no more trouble, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes it solves the problem above @Garf365 solved the other problem with xInstance[4] aswell. Thanks for all your help and sorry for the wrong tagging, was my first time posting here.

Comment: It's not to late to change tagging ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your second hidden question, with 4 elements, you miss some brackets:

```
// Note double brackets
#define DEFAULT_EEprom_Mapping  {{ DEFAULT_INSTANCE_BLOCK, DEFAULT_INSTANCE_BLOCK, DEFAULT_INSTANCE_BLOCK, DEFAULT_INSTANCE_BLOCK }}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/FS3mZa)

Indeed, `xInstance` is an array inside a structure, so you need brackets for initializer list of structure and brackets for initializer list of array.

Answer (score 2):

Your array `xInstance` is an array of size `0`, so the compiler complains because you try to fit one element in it.

Comment: Wow, sorry i'm stupid. That fixes the problem for one block thanks, but if i try the same with 4 Blocks with xInstance[4] and 4 blocks in the DEFAULT_EEprom_Mapping i get the same error..